# Find all number $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\varphi (n)=8$

Tags: totient-function

$n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\varphi (n)=8$

I know for formula  $\varphi (n)=n\prod\limits_{p|n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$ where p is prime number.

I choose $p=2$ and with formula I get that $n=16$, so it is ok, then I choose $p=2,3$ and using formula I get $n=24$, then $p=2,3,5$ and I get $n=30$ and that is ok, but if I choose $p=2,3,5,7$ then I can not get a number such that $\varphi (n)=8$ and I try other number and the result is the same, so is it ok that only number $n=16, n=24, n=30,$ or I need to write on other way?

Comment: So $\rho(n)=\varphi(n)$?

Comment: Standard notation is $\varphi(n)$. ..."\varphi(n)"

Comment: Hint:  if $p$ is an odd prime dividing $n$ what can you say about $p-1$?

Comment: If $p\mid n$ then $(p-1)\mid 8$, so $p\in\{2,3,5\}$. If $p^2\mid n$ then $p=2$. Also $2^5\nmid n$. That should narrow down the search space.

Comment: is it same as Euler's $\phi$ or totient function?